# Google Cloud Natural Language Python "cannot import name 'enums' from 'google.cloud.language_v1'"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nlp

I'm trying to run a simple Python code on windows but having problem with enums.

I did following things and installed google-cloud-language.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-language
```

And my code is:

```
import os
from google.cloud import language_v1
from google.cloud.language_v1 import enums
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import types
```

And I'm getting this error:

cannot import name 'enums' from 'google.cloud.language_v1' (D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\language_v1_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Migration Guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/language/latest/UPGRADING.html#enums-and-types), the submodule enums have been removed.

You can check the current language_v1 Information [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.language.v1).

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can find a useful example of how to import language_v1 [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/samples/language-entities-gcs#language_entities_gcs-python).

You can try something similar to this;

```
from google.cloud import language_v1

client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

type_ = language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
```